# Log file reading and finding a value string

Tags: batch-file

I have got a log file which contains the below lines in it.

> Total tests: 1. Passed: 0. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0. 
>   Test execution time: 3.5167 Minutes 
>   Total tests: 1. Passed: 0. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0.

```
@Echo off
Set "log_file=Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log"
Call :Main
GoTo :EOF

:Main
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /i "Failed: 0." %log_file%') do (
  set line=%%i
  HERE I NEED HELP
)
Exit /B
```

When there is a value which is like **Failed: 1** an email to be initiated with the log file as an attachment.  If **Failed: 0.** do nothing.

@Mofi I added the code like this, is this how it should be?

```
@Echo off
Set "log_file=Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log"
Call :Main
GoTo :EOF

:Main
findstr /R /C:"^Total tests: .*Failed: [123456789]" %log_file% >nul
if not errorlevel 1 
echo Send the log file Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log with an email.
Exit /B
```

Comment: use `find` instead of `findstr` (same syntax). `findstr "a b"` finds every line that contains `a` and/or `b`. (or use `findstr /ilc:"Failed: 0."` for the whole literal string)

Comment: Note that `HERE I NEED HELP` will be executed for each finding (two times with your example log (at least))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it only matters if the log file contains the string `Failed: X` with `X` being a number greater `0`. For that reason the **FOR** loop is not necessary at all. It is enough to search entire file for such a string, perhaps in right context like there must be `Total tests:` at beginning of the line to avoid false positives, and just evaluate next if the string is found in the log file or not.

What happens on running the following command line as in code in question?

```
findstr /i "Failed: 0." Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log
```

There is only specified the option `/i` to do a case-insensitive search.

There is neither used option `/L` to explicitly request a literal search nor the option `/R` to explicitly request a regular expression search. The search string is specified with just putting it in double quotes. In this case **FINDSTR** analyzes the search string and determines itself if using a literal or a regular expression search.

A search string specified in double quotes containing a space character is interpreted as regular expression string with interpreting the space as **OR** expression.

The execution of `findstr /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window outputs the help of command **FINSTR** describing the regular expression characters and their meanings.

The usage of `/C:"Failed: 0"` would result by default in a literal search (`/L` is used implicit on not being specified explicit) with interpreting the space character as literal space and **not** as **OR** expression. That is the most important difference between `"search string"` and `/C:"search string"`. The space in `/C:"search string"` is always interpreted as literal character, even on using additionally `/R` to run a regular expression search with the search string in double quotes after `/C:`. The space in argument `"search string"` without `/C:` is interpreted as space only on using additionally option `/L`. The space is interpreted as **OR** expression on using `"search string"` with `/R` or without `/L`.

Conclusion:

```
findstr "word1 word2 word3"
findstr /R "word1 word2 word3"
```

**FINDSTR** is searching with a regular expression for lines containing `word1` **OR** `word2` **OR** `word3`.

```
findstr /C:"word 1" /C:"word 2" /C:"word 3"
findstr /L /C:"word 1" /C:"word 2" /C:"word 3"
```

**FINDSTR** is searching with a literal search for lines containing `word 1` **OR** `word 2` **OR** `word 3` with space being interpreted as space.

It is advisable to always use `/L` or `/R` to make it 100% clear for **FINDSTR** and for readers of the command line if `"search string"` or `/C:"search string"` is interpreted as literal search string or as regular expression search string.

So this command line results in searching for lines containing case-insensitive either the string `Failed:` **OR** the string `0`. Such this search is definitely not wanted here as it will always finds the line with `Failed:` independent on the number.

The value of **FINDSTR** returned to calling process on exit is `0` on at least one line found matching the search criteria (search successful) or `1` on no line found matching the search criteria (search failed). The exit code of **FINDSTR** is assigned by `cmd.exe` calling `findstr.exe` to `ERRORLEVEL`.

So the following code could be used to search **case-sensitive** for a line starting with `Total tests:` and containing also `Failed:`  with next character being a digit greater `0` and evaluate the exit code for success on finding a line matching the search criteria.

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"^Total tests: .*Failed: [123456789]" Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo Send the log file Automation_Log_20191125_1853_06.log with an email.
```

A search string specified with `/C:` is by default interpreted as literal search string, but `/R` overrides that and so the search string is interpreted as regular expression string, but with space being interpreted as space character and not as **OR** expression as it would be the case on omitting `/C:`. `^` means beginning of line and `.*` means any character 0 or more times and `[123456789]` means one of the characters inside the square brackets.

The lines output by **FINDSTR** on a positive match are suppressed by redirecting them to device **NUL** as those lines are not really needed.

It is only of interest if **FINDSTR** exited with a value less than 1 which means with value 0 because that means the log file contains a line reporting at least one failed operation.

See also the help output on running `if /?` and read:

- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))